# JMML Apache Spark org.dmg.pmml.MiningField.setUsageType function not found error

Tags: apache-spark, pmml

I am getting the following error while trying to convert a PipeLine Model in spark to Pmml using JPmml.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.dmg.pmml.MiningField.setUsageType(Lorg/dmg/pmml/MiningField$UsageType;)Lorg/dmg/pmml/MiningField;

I have added all the dependencies regarding JPmml.

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jpmml/jpmml-sparkml
libraryDependencies += "org.jpmml" % "jpmml-sparkml" % "1.1.6"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jpmml/pmml-model
libraryDependencies += "org.jpmml" % "pmml-model" % "1.3.6"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jpmml/pmml-evaluator
libraryDependencies += "org.jpmml" % "pmml-evaluator" % "1.3.5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have added all the dependencies regarding JPmml.

You have added all dependencies, but your application can't see them, because in your application classpath, there is an Apache Spark ML provided `org.jpmml:pmml-model:1.2.X` (has method `MiningField#setFieldUsage(MiningField$FieldUsage)`), which shadows your `org.jpmml:pmml-model:1.3.X` (has method `MiningField#setUsageType(MiningField$UsageType)`): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15526

You should stop reinventing the wheel, and use the [JPMML-SparkML-Package](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml-package) library. This application classpath/packaging issue is specifically covered in its documentation.

Comment: Thanks for helping now code works fine on continuous features,but still i am not able to use Categorical variables. It gives error  Model not created:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jpmml.converter.BinaryFeature cannot be cast to org.jpmml.converter.ContinuousFeature

Comment: Must be the same thing: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jpmml/R6t8L0pAkoc In brief, you should replace all casts with `Feature#toContinuousFeature()` method invocations

Comment: I have used String Indexer and One Hot Encoder to convert them to continuous features and then assembled categorical and continuous using vector assembler.

Comment: The use of OneHotEncoder means that a feature has "categorical" operational type. Perhaps you shouldn't be using this feature in contexts that require "continuous" operational type? If you don't like the idea of modifying JPMML-SparkML for the time being, then it may be possible to avoid this ClassCastException by simply refactoring your pipeline - change the order of steps, assemble partial vectors not complete vectors, etc.

Comment: what can I use in place of one hot encoder or can u tell what can I use to use categorical features in regression?

Comment: Where exactly does this `ClassCastException` occur? There are many "vulnerabilities" in that part of JPMML-SparkML codebase that deals with transformation conversions, but not a single one that deals with regression model conversions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138287/discussion-between-tejasvi-sharma-and-user1808924).